# Silverlight compatible Telnet/SSH library

Tags: silverlight, ssh, telnet

Is there a Silverlight compatible Telnet or SSH library.

Answer (score 1):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssh.php) product includes SSH client components, which can be used in Silverlight (subject to network access restrictions, imposed by Microsoft on Silverlight code). 
Telnet is "low-level" TCP access + handling of some control sequences. While SecureBlackbox doesn't include control sequence interpretation (neither it does for SSH), you can use TElSocket class for simple synchronous socket access (also in Silverlight) and add control sequence handling.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open source projects out there that implement SSH, mostly deriving from [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx), such as [SharpSSH2](http://sharpssh2.codeplex.com/) which is "updated for the v3.5 framework", and a rewrite for the v4 framework is [SSH.Net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) (although it also claims to support ".NET 3.5, Silverlight and Windows Phone"). There are other projects such as [Granados](http://granados.sourceforge.net/) as well, so depending on your preference of open source licence, you may find one of these will suit your needs.